# Group and show extra column's distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sum

How do I get this result? It sums over a and shows distinct values of b.

| a | b | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9274 | 83 |
| 1 | 2746 | 83 |
| 1 | 1847 | 83 |
| 2 | 6564 | 83 |
| 2 | 8274 | 83 |
| 2 | 8567 | 83 |

The following query only sums over a

```
SELECT a, SUM(quantiy) AS sum
FROM table
GROUP BY a
```

| a | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 83 |
| 2 | 83 |

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a `group by` clause, you can use the window variant of the `sum` function and use a `partition by` clause for it:

```sql
SELECT a, b, SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY a)
FROM   my_table;
```

**[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fa92e/2)**

Comment: Wow that's exactly what i need, and that fiddle works very well!